# How to find the coordinates of the fourth vertex of a square in a projective perspective

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, projection, perspective, perspectivecamera

If I suppose that I know the coordinate of three points (eg. `A'B'C'`) in a 2D coordinate system of `A'B'C'D'`, my question is how can I find the coordinate of the fourth point `D'` (the same question for `A''B''C''D''`)? Is it even possible? Do I need more information?

For the rectangle ABCD would be easy to get the coordinates of `D` knowing `ABC`, because it is a normal square in a euclidean geometry, using the simple formula: $$A+B-C,\ A+C-B~or \ B+C-A$$

[image]

The projection used in here is a perspective projection like a pinhole model used by cameras. I do know the intrinsic parameters of the camera (focal length, pixels size..etc) and also the size of the square in real world, however, I don't know the distance `Z` of that square from the camera. Here is the parameters I know about the projection:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/camera-calibration.html

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Do you want to know where is D' or D?

Comment: Not D but its projection in the image, knowing the coordinates of A’, B’ and C’ (or any other three) where the fourth point D’ is projected?